# Lookup user field in flow is not working with Record Id value populated

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-flows

In my scratch org I have a flow to create opportunity and also set owner Id using a custom lookup field. This lookup field works fine (and searches users) when no value is provided to 'Record Id' input variable.

1. When I set it to current user ($user.Id) it stops working and throws an error - "An error occurred on
   this Lookup component. Contact your Salesforce admin for help."
2. Even when I hard code the user id (005xxxx..) in Record Id parameter it still fails and just stops
   working with this error message.

However, this works fine in sandboxes but has just stopped working in scratch org since yesterday. I am not sure what could have happened to cause this.

Comment: Hi. Did you try [debugging the flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_test_debug.htm&type=5)? Have you turned on [debug logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) and looked to see if more error detail is available in there?

Comment: Yeah, nothing showed up in debug logs.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be weirdest of scratch org issues. Page layout assignment was not set for 'User Profile Page Layouts'. After assigning the page layout to all the profiles flow lookup started working as usual. Only common thing between the two is User object. It is beyond me how page layout assignment impacted the flow lookup component. Very strange!